# PHP: Uploading File In a Network Folder

Tags: php, upload, network-programming, directory

I'm trying to write an application to upload files into a network folder. Here is my code:

```
    $root = "\\\\TEST04\\STORAGE\\MIDIA\\";
    $dir = "26172"; //Hardcoded for testing reasons
    echo " ".$root." is_writable? ".var_export(is_writable($root))."<br />"; //Returns TRUE
    echo " ".$root." is_dir? ".var_export(is_dir($root))."<br />"; //Returns TRUE

    foreach($_FILES['anexo']['name'] as $key => $value) {
        $name = $_FILES['anexo']['name'][$key];
        if(!move_uploaded_file($name, $root."\\".$dir."\\".$name)) {
            echo "Upload error in file $name em $root\\\\$dir\\\\$name <br />";
            print_r(error_get_last());
        } else {
            echo "Upload of file $name complete.";
        }
    }
```

But it always catch an error. _error_get_last()_ is always empty.

**move_uploaded_file** returns **false**. **copy** also returns false.

Please help! Many thanks.